# Colorless Computer Vision: Object Recognition through Depth Data or Point Clouds?
Why it always shows REQUIRED process [rviz-9] has died! whenever i r

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to know if their is any computer vision algorithm which dont uses color data and still does the task of object recognition, tracking etc. Is their such method or 3d computer vision thing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234428/is-their-any-method-by-which-i-can-do-computer-vision-task-like-object-recognition,-whithout-using-color-information,-just-by-analysing-the-depth-data-or-point-cloud?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe the Pointcloud Library (PCL) is what you are searching for:
http://pointclouds.org/

I personally haven't used it yet, so I cannot help you any further.

---

Originally posted by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) with karma: 305 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0